# How to evaluate $\int\frac{3x^{2}+7}{\sqrt{x^{4}+5x^{2}+9}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Q) How to evaluate $$\int\frac{3x^{2}+7}{\sqrt{x^{4}+5x^{2}+9}}dx$$?

Ans): First of all let me show my approach.
I wrote the above integral as $$\int\frac{3x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{4}+5x^{2}+9}}dx+\int\frac{7}{\sqrt{x^{4}+5x^{2}+9}}dx$$.
Now $x^{4}+5x^{2}+9$ can be factorized as $x^{4}+5x^{2}+9=(x^{2})^{2}+2(\frac{5}{2})(x^{2})+(\frac{5}{2})^{2}+9-(\frac{5}{2})^{2}=(x^{2}+\frac{5}{2})^{2}+\frac{11}{4}$.

Therefore let's integrate $$\int\frac{3x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{4}+5x^{2}+9}}dx$$ first.

$$\int\frac{3x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{4}+5x^{2}+9}}dx=3\int\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{4}+5x^{2}+9}}dx=3\int\frac{(x)(x)}{\sqrt{x^{4}+5x^{2}+9}}dx=3\int\frac{(x)(x)}{(x^{2}+\frac{5}{2})^{2}+\frac{11}{4}}dx=$$

$$\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{(x)(2x)}{\sqrt{(x^{2}+\frac{5}{2})^{2}+\frac{11}{4}}}dx$$
Now let's substitute $(x^{2}+\frac{5}{2})=t$. Therefore $2xdx=dt$. Therefore the integral $$\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{(x)(2x)}{\sqrt{(x^{2}+\frac{5}{2})^{2}+\frac{11}{4}}}dx$$ can be evaluated  by applying Integration By Parts. Here we have to consider $u=x$ and $v=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{(x^{2}+\frac{5}{2})^{2}+\frac{11}{4}}}$.

Therefore the result of the integration of the $1st$ part will be $$\frac{3}{2}[x\int\frac{2x}{\sqrt{(x^{2}+\frac{5}{2})^{2}+\frac{11}{4}}}dx-\int\frac{d}{dx}(x)\int\frac{2x}{\sqrt{(x^{2}+\frac{5}{2})^{2}+\frac{11}{4}}}dx]=\frac{3}{2}[x\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^{2}+\frac{11}{4}}}dt-\int\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^{2}+\frac{11}{4}}}dt]=\frac{3}{2}[x\log|t+\sqrt{t^{2}+\frac{11}{4}}|-\int\log|t+\sqrt{t^{2}+\frac{11}{4}}|dt]=\frac{3}{2}[x\log|(x^{2}+\frac{5}{2})+\sqrt{(x^{2}+\frac{5}{2})^{2}+\frac{11}{4}}|-\int\log|t+\sqrt{t^{2}+\frac{11}{4}}|dt]$$.
And after this step I can't proceed further in integrating the $1st$ part, i.e. $$\int\frac{3x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{4}+5x^{2}+9}}dx$$.
But still once confirm whether my procedure is correct or not.

Now also we can write the $2nd$ part as $$\int\frac{7}{\sqrt{(x^{2}+\frac{5}{2})^{2}+\frac{11}{4}}}dx$$. But I don't know how to integrate the $2nd$ part. Please help me out with the evaluation of the above integral.

Comment: Ok. I have edited the title now.@rschwieb.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti Thanks for understanding!

Comment: [Integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) didn't find the antiderivative, that doesn't necessarily have to mean something, but are you sure it has an "elementary" integral? Did you get that exercice in a textbook or did you invent the integral by yourself?

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti: There appears to be no solution in elementary functions, see this [*Wolfram Alpha*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%283*x%5E2+%2B+7%29%2FSqrt%5Bx%5E4+%2B+5*x%5E2+%2B+9%5D) result, which is potentially wrong, and the previous comment says that another integrator failed..

Comment: This integral, like most involving the square root of a quartic polynomial, does not have a closed expression in terms of elementary functions; it can be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral

Comment: That's why I gave this integral here. If I put now lower and upper limits to this integral, then it will give a real value.  For e.g. $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(3x^{2}+7)}{\sqrt{(x^{4}+5x^{2}+9)}}$ will give a specific real value of $2.42$?

Comment: No. Actually, this question was given to me by one of my elder brother. He said to me that this question was asked to the professors of his University by an another student. Since my elder brother is not a member of this community so he told me to get some help in this question. So, I asked this question here. Currently he is pursuing MSc from University Of Rajasthan. His $2nd$ year is going on there

Answer (score 1):

*Just for your curiosity.*

As said, this would involve elliptic integrals.

To give you a taste, consider the case of
$$I=\int \frac {x^2+a}{\sqrt {(x^2+b)\,(x^2+c)}}\,dx$$ Skipping the intermediate steps and simplifications
$$\color{blue}{I=\frac{i}{\sqrt{c}}\Bigg((c-a)\, F\left(i \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{b}}\right)\bigg|\frac{b}{c}\right)-c \,E\left(i \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{b}}\right)\bigg|\frac{b}{c}\right) \Bigg)}$$ where appear the elliptic integrals of the first and second kinds.

The problem is still more nasty if, as in your case, $b$ and $c$ are complex conjugate.

For your specific case where $a=\frac 7 3$, $b=\frac{5+i \sqrt{11}}{2}$ and $c=\frac{5-i \sqrt{11}}{2}$ and bounds $(0,1)$, the result will be $0.809427$ which, more or less, corresponds to one third of $2.42$.

Comment: Here you have mentioned $I=\int \frac{(x^{2}+a)}{\sqrt{(x^{2}+b)(x^{2}+c)}}dx$. But I don't think that $(x^{2}+\frac{5}{2})^{2}+\frac{11}{4}$ can be mentioned in the form of $(x^{2}+b)(x^{2}+c)$ @Claude Leibovici

Comment: @SyamaprasadChakrabarti. Just expand $(x^{2}+b)(x^{2}+c)$ and compare to $(x^{2}+\frac{5}{2})^{2}+\frac{11}{4}$